# EmberJs - Getting json data to the view

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js

This will be something extremely simple but at the moment I am having trouble working out how to get my json data into a my view template.

For my index page I have the following code:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var pageContent = App.Content.find(1);

  }
});
```

Which is returning the JSON I need for the page content with the ID of 1. (This works as I see the results in firebug console.

It's returning the following json

```
{"content":[{"id":"1","name":"Home","extended":"This is the homepage.","created":"2013-08-05 23:40:55","modified":"2013-08-05 23:40:55"}]}
```

I have this view setup but I cannot work how how to get the data from json to the view:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
<div class='index'>
  {{pageContent.entended}}

    The home page
</div>
```

P.s. I only just started with EmberJS so I assume this will be extremely simple.

Thanks

Comment: edited my answer, you have also a bad formatted JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually return the results from your model hook:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Content.find(1);
  }
});
```

And then in your template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
  <div class='index'>
  {{model.extended}}
  The home page
</div>
```

As for your JSON, it should have this format:

```
{
  "content": {
    "id":"1",
    "name":"Home",
    "extended":"This is the homepage.",
    "created":"2013-08-05 23:40:55",
    "modified":"2013-08-05 23:40:55"
  }
}
```

Notice the removed `[]`.

[Simple Demo here](http://jsbin.com/uyuliy/2/edit).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, yes it was the square brackets causing me issues. Thanks for your help.